# Scanning a string line by line

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, nsscanner

I have an nsstring with 50 of lines i want to scan a particular string using nsscanner scanning  each lines.

Is it possible ?

Can anyone help me?

Thanks in advance......

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is possible; you just need to split the string, and then scan each line for the string you are looking for.

Why are you using `NSScanner`? Would not it be easier to simply search for the string?